# Mule - queue files so that only one file is passed through flow at any one time

Tags: file, queue, mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule flow that is listening in on two file locations in a composite source. Is there a way I can restrict my flow from only processing one file at a time if two files were to drop in the locations at the same time?

Essentially, the way I'd like my application to work is if two files are dropped at the same time, Mule picks up one, processes it, and **only when the flow has finished** start processing the next file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at processing strategies: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies

It will allow you to set the amount of threads to throttle your flows.

```
<queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy name="allow1Threads" maxThreads="1" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>

<flow name="testFlow" processingStrategy="allow1Threads">
   <file:inbound... />
   <flow-ref name="processFile" />
</flow>

<flow name="processFile" processingStrategy="synchronous">
  <!-- Synchronous processing here -->
</flow>
```

UPDATE: As per the comment, I have updated the example. This will allow you to throttle the main flow to 1 thread and pass it to "processFile" which will run synchronously.

Also even if the main flow is async, (which is default for file inbound endpoints because it is one-way exchange pattern, unless you have overridden the processingStrategy or exchange-pattern) flow components still run synchronously in terms of order, **EXCEPT** for flow-refs to private flows where they automatically pick up the calling flows processing strategy.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. Will this allow the flow (eg testFlow) to run synchronously? I need each flow component to run in order. My current processing strategy is synchronous.

Comment: Sort of, I have updated the example to show one possible way of achieving what you want.

Comment: I am curious on this : can you tell me why you may need only one at a time. Even though it is two different folders and only thread will be different for each file from the different location.I will be great if you would help me understand the need of this scenario

Comment: Hi @Naveen, the reason I need to one at a time is because I'm using an in-memory database to process flat files. If two files are processed at once then they are both written to the database at the same time and my output file is essentially a combination of the two inputs. I need to process one file at a time so it follows: 1. file comes in, 2. DB cleared, 3. file processed etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way for your flow.

```
<flow name="fileFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
   <file:inbound... />
   <remaining Flow>
   ......
</flow>
```

This way there will always be only one thread to pick and process the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't be able to use a single inbound endpoint as the two files are coming from different locations, unless there is a way (other than a composite source) to achieve this in one inbound endpoint?

Comment: When reading from two different locations, why not to go for a Composite source. Is the processing logic different for both these files?

Comment: I am using a composite source, and the processing logic is the same for both files. The issue I have is as stated in the above comments, that if two files are placed in the locations at the same time, they are both read together and inserted into the temp DB together - meaning that the second output file (all rows in the DB) will be a combination of the first and second input files. I need a way for a flow to detect a single file, and only move on to processing another file when the entire flow has finished...

Comment: Composite source along with Synchronous strategy should solve the problem. Are you using it the same way?